# sed appending after regex capture

Tags: sed

```
roger
tennis
federer
hello
```

Once I match the string "tennis", I need o/p like the below.

roger federer
   tennis
   hello

trial from my end :

```
sed '$!N;s/\n\s*{\s*$/{/;P;D' file
```

Comment: a bit of code formatting

Comment: it is difficult to understand what you need.. the code you tried doesn't use `tennis` at all.. please try to explain the transformation process.. for ex: are you trying to match three consecutive lines with `tennis` in middle line and change the order as `line 1 space line 3` followed by `line 2` ?

Comment: [`perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(tennis)\n(.+)/ $2\n\n$1\n/g'`](https://ideone.com/v3EiuZ)?

Comment: @Wicktor Thank you this helped me. but may i know how this .+ would work ?